# Confusion around MVC routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a quick question around MVC and calling a method from JavaScript.

I need to create a controller that works in the following manner:

```
/Marvel/Spiderman
```

Where `{Spiderman}` will be the name of the comic I need to pass through.

From my understanding (very little) of MVC, the route for this should look like `{ controller = "Marvel", id = UrlParameter.Required }`

The controller:

```
MarvelController: Controller
{
    // this is where I'm confused
}
```

I cannot call a action on here, as the route does not dictate an action /{controller}/{id} or am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should 'hard-code' you action name in the route, so that the Router will know what action to call. You can do it with the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "ComicRoute",
     url: "Marvel/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Marvel", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And you controller will look like this:

```
MarvelController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id) {....}
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this will not work, as the route is looking for a view. i want this route attached to a controller without a route :$

Comment: What do you mean by 'route is looking for a view'?

Comment: i'm being stupid, because I was returning View() :$, however, /Marvel/ works, but /Marvel/Spiderman returns 404 :(

Comment: Are you sure that you've put this route above the default route?

Comment: if i do that, my default routes don't fire, it trying to run this route on http://www.mycomicbookshop.com/ which should infact run the default route. this stuff is so confusing :(

Comment: I've modified the answer, just hard-code the controller name and it will work. It indeed overrides the default route

Comment: got it working thanks, yes, it makes sense to hard-code the controller name :'). thank you